# Cambiar color de icono al llenar input de formulario

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tengo un Login que dentro de su input tiene un icono dentro de un span. Lo que deseo es que cuando el input este lleno por el id del usuario y pase al password, el icono cambie a color verde (para indicar, y estética).
Como puedo lograrlo? dejo el código que eh usado en html y una imagen de los inputs.

```html
<div class="input-icon">
  <input type="text" id="user" name="usuario" maxlength="15" placeholder="Usuario" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event)" required >
  <span class="lnr lnr-users icon3"></span>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: no incluiste el codigo ni la imagen

Comment: @JeffCasino La pregunta tenía un problema de formato.

Comment: @mafu Aunque si incluiste código e imagen las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración de código deben incluir un [mcve] (falta el CSS y el Javascript)

Comment: lo mas simple es que uses jQuery, has una funcion que cambie la clase de linput que quieres colocar en verde, y llamas a esa funcion por medio de .focusout() https://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Comment: Ya intentaste usar Javascript? porque solo con html no te va a funcionar, y si ya lo hiciste pon tu codigo para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 5):

Podes usar la pseudo-clase [`:valid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:valid). Como el input tiene un `required`, en cuanto escribís un carácter, se le aplica `:valid`.

Se puede resolver con CSS en la medida que el ícono esté después del input (por como funcionan los selectores), si estuviera antes tendrías que utilizar JavaScript.

```css
.lnr {
  color: #ccc;
}

#user:valid + .lnr {
  color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-icon">
  <input type="text" id="user" name="usuario" maxlength="15" placeholder="Usuario" required>
  <span class="lnr lnr-users icon3">Ícono</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución podría ser esta:

```css
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
}

body
{
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

section
{
  background-color: #f2f2f7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 50%;
}

h1
{
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}

input
{
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/XmrvrGt.png');
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 10%;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: .5em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  width: 100%;
}

input:invalid
{
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/mOsYsfn.png');
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Username</h1>
  <input pattern="[a-z]{1,15}">
</section>
```

Comment: recuerda agregar una explicación, para identificar como este script ayuda a solucionar el problema planteado por el OP.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy de acuerdo con @azeós: puedes utilizar la pseudo-clase `:valid`. Como icon utilizaría elementos SVG cuyo `stroke` es el `currentColor`

En el input he añadido: `pattern="\w{5,10}"`. Esto dice que el valor del input tiene que ser alpha numeric entre 5 y 10 caracteres. si el valor introducido no cumple esta condición el color cambia al inicial

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
input{height:24px;}
.input-icon{display:flex;}

.lnr {
  color: #333;
}

#user:valid + .lnr {
  color: #0f0;
}

.lnr svg{stroke:currentColor}
```

```html
<div class="input-icon">
  <input type="text" id="user" name="usuario" maxlength="15" placeholder="Usuario" pattern="\w{5,10}" required >
  <span class="lnr lnr-users icon3">
    
    <svg width='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>person outline</title>
<path d='M12 5.9c1.16 0 2.1.94 2.1 2.1s-.94 2.1-2.1 2.1-2.1-.94-2.1-2.1.94-2.1 2.1-2.1m0 9c2.97 0 6.1 1.46 6.1 2.1v1.1h-12.2v-1.1c0-.64 3.13-2.1 6.1-2.1m0-10.9c-2.21 0-4 1.79-4 4s1.79 4 4 4 4-1.79 4-4-1.79-4-4-4zm0 9c-2.67 0-8 1.34-8 4v3h16v-3c0-2.66-5.33-4-8-4z'></path>
</svg>
    
  </span>
</div>
```